# Empty dropdownlist from database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm working on a legacy code, and I'm stuck with a DropDownList that's empty. Here's the code:

```
private void CarregarCheckboxPesquisas()
    {
        string sqlConexaoString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sql_Interno"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConexao = new SqlConnection(sqlConexaoString);

        ArrayList listaPesquisas = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList listacodPesquisas = new ArrayList();
        listaPesquisas.Add("Selecione uma pesquisa");
        listacodPesquisas.Add("");


        try
        {
            string sqlComandoString = "SELECT codPesquisa, titulo FROM Pesquisas ORDER BY codPesquisa DESC;";
            SqlCommand sqlComando = new SqlCommand(sqlComandoString, sqlConexao);
            sqlConexao.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr1 = sqlComando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (dr1.Read())
            {
                listacodPesquisas.Add(dr1.GetString(0));
                listaPesquisas.Add(dr1.GetString(1));
            }
            dr1.Close();
            sqlConexao.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("########## Erro na obtenção dos valores das questões: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listacodPesquisas.Count; i++)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem(listaPesquisas[i].ToString(), listacodPesquisas[i].ToString());
            DDLPesquisa.Items.Add(li);
            //DDLPesquisa.Items.Add(new ListItem(listaPesquisas[i].ToString, listacodPesquisas[i].ToString()));
        }

    }
```

I already checked the SQL connection, it's working fine. So, I assume it must be something else, but I failed at discovering what. I did my research, and still nothing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there an error? When you attach the debugger does it go thru the loop and are the values not null?

Comment: Have you tried `DDLPesquisa.Items.Insert(DDLPesquisa.Items.Count - 1,li);` ?

Comment: No, no errors. The process just executes fine, only with no items on the list.

Comment: I'll try it now, posting results soon

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi I tried what you said, it showed me an exception error saying "The insertion index was out of range. It must be non-negative and less than or equal to size." Other values resulted in error too

Comment: @MPS: You're populating the list as new one. So don't use `DDLPesquisa.Items.Count - 1` instead use **0** like this `DDLPesquisa.Items.Insert(0,li);`

Comment: @MPS: Also try the solution which I posted below as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving it an `index` and also `items.Insert` like this

```
DDLPesquisa.Items.Insert(0,li);
```

Or you can also Bind your DropDownList this way:

```
try
    {
        string sqlComandoString = "SELECT codPesquisa, titulo FROM Pesquisas ORDER BY codPesquisa DESC;";
        SqlCommand sqlComando = new SqlCommand(sqlComandoString, sqlConexao);
        sqlConexao.Open();
        DDLPesquisa.DataSource = sqlComando.ExecuteReader();
        DDLPesquisa.DataTextField = "titulo";
        DDLPesquisa.DataValueField = "codPesquisa";
        DDLPesquisa.DataBind();
        sqlConexao.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("########## Erro na obtenção dos valores das questões: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: It works! Really thanks, man! I'll try on the other way you suggested too, for learning!

Answer (score 1):

Kinda thinking simple here so dont criticize me but are you sure listacodPesquisas is not empty or null. See if you can output the list before you add it to the drop down. Also does it give you an error or just shows empty?

Comment: Checked it out, @Diesel298, really empty. And yes, just empty, no errors.